# filter JSON data by current date using Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter JSON data by current date using Angular. I have seen some similar posts but I can't seem to implement the answers correctly. I attempted to write a custom filter comparing `today` which is the name of the var holding my date object with `doc.date` which is the JSON location of the date entry I want to filter.

My JSON data looks like this:

```
var books = 

[  
   {  
      "doc":{  
         "date":"07/14",
         "title":"A Nourishing Ingredient",
         "quote":"Where humility had formerly stood for a forced feeding on humble pie, it now begins to mean the nourishing ingredient which can give us serenity.",
         "attribution":"page 74",
         "text":"How often do I focus on my problems and frustrations? When I am having a 'good day' these same problems shrink in importance and my preoccupation with them dwindles. Wouldn't it be better if I could find a key to unlock the 'magic' of my 'good days' for use on the woes of my 'bad days?'. I already have the solution! Instead of trying to run away from my pain and wish my problems away, I can pray for humility! Humility will heal the pain. Humility will take me out of myself. Humility, that strength granted to me by that 'power greater than myself,' is mine for the asking! Humility will bring balance back into my life. Humility will allow me to accept my humanness joyously."
  }
 },
{  
  "doc":{  
     "date":"07/15",
     "title":"Pride",
     "quote":"Time and again I approached the Seventh Step, only to fall back and regroup. Something was missing and the impact of the Step escaped me. What had I overlooked? A single word: read but ignored, the foundation of all the Steps, indeed the entire Alcoholics Anonymous program – that word is 'humbly.' I understood my shortcomings: I constantly put tasks off; I angered easily; I felt too much self-pity; and I thought, why me? Then I remembered, 'Pride goeth before the fall,' and I eliminated pride from my life."
  }
}
]
```

My JS:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;//January is 0, so always add + 1

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd}
if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
today = mm+'/'+dd;
console.log(today);

var myApplication = angular.module('myApp', ['ngColorThis']);

myApplication.controller("Catalog", function ($scope) {

$scope.books = books;


})

.filter('mydate', function() {

            return function (doc.date, today) {
            return doc.date < today;
        };

    });
```

My html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Catalog">


<div  ng-repeat="book in books | mydate" color-this="background-color" data-color="book.doc.title">
    <div  >
    <div class="date">{{book.doc.date}}</div>
    <div class="title">{{book.doc.title}}</div>
    <div class="quote">{{book.doc.quote}}</div>
    <div class="attribution">{{book.doc.attribution}}</div>
    <div class="text">{{book.doc.text}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below code. Hope this will help you.

```js
var myApplication = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApplication.controller("Catalog", function($scope) {
  var books = [{
    "doc": {
      "date": "07/15",
      "title": "A Nourishing Ingredient",
      "quote": "Where humility had formerly stood for a forced feeding on humble pie, it now begins to mean the nourishing ingredient which can give us serenity.",
      "attribution": "page 74",
      "text": "How often do I focus on my problems and frustrations? When I am having a 'good day' these same problems shrink in importance and my preoccupation with them dwindles. Wouldn't it be better if I could find a key to unlock the 'magic' of my 'good days' for use on the woes of my 'bad days?'. I already have the solution! Instead of trying to run away from my pain and wish my problems away, I can pray for humility! Humility will heal the pain. Humility will take me out of myself. Humility, that strength granted to me by that 'power greater than myself,' is mine for the asking! Humility will bring balance back into my life. Humility will allow me to accept my humanness joyously."
    }
  }, {
    "doc": {
      "date": "07/16",
      "title": "Pride",
      "quote": "Time and again I approached the Seventh Step, only to fall back and regroup. Something was missing and the impact of the Step escaped me. What had I overlooked? A single word: read but ignored, the foundation of all the Steps, indeed the entire Alcoholics Anonymous program – that word is 'humbly.' I understood my shortcomings: I constantly put tasks off; I angered easily; I felt too much self-pity; and I thought, why me? Then I remembered, 'Pride goeth before the fall,' and I eliminated pride from my life."
    }
  }]
  $scope.books = books;
});

myApplication.filter('mydate', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0, so always add + 1
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
      dd = '0' + dd
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
      mm = '0' + mm
    }
    today = mm + '/' + dd;
    return (input == today)
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Catalog">
    <div ng-repeat="book in books" color-this="background-color" data-color="book.doc.title">
      <div ng-show=" book.doc.date | mydate">
        <div class="date">{{book.doc.date}}</div>
        <div class="title">{{book.doc.title}}</div>
        <div class="quote">{{book.doc.quote}}</div>
        <div class="attribution">{{book.doc.attribution}}</div>
        <div class="text">{{book.doc.text}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Recommended: These kind of business logic should be place in service for better performance in real world case.**